# scala type erasure and value classes

Tags: scala, type-erasure

I am trying to get around type erasure and dynamically convert a list of values of varying types using value classes to json and back to the respective types using Json4s CustomSerializer. However, I have been unable to dynamically extract correct values. Due to the reference to AnyVal, I am forced to use value.toString when converting to Json and am facing issues when I recreate my fields from json.

I've been trying my hand at scala for three weeks now, so I am still learning the ropes. Any help would be appreciated.

```
abstract class MyVal {
  def name: String
  def value: AnyVal
}

trait Field {
  def value: AnyVal
}

object Field {
  def build(value: String): MyString = MyString(value)
  def build(value: Int): MyInt = MyInt(value)
  def build(value: Double): MyDouble = MyDouble(value)
}
case class MyString(val value: String) extends AnyVal with Field
case class MyInt(val value: Int) extends AnyVal with Field
case class MyDouble(val value: Double) extends AnyVal with Field


object MyVal {
  case class StringVal(name: String, value: MyString) extends MyVal
  case class IntVal(name: String, value: MyInt) extends MyVal
  case class DoubleVal(name: String, value: MyDouble) extends MyVal

  def build(name: String, value: String): StringVal = StringVal(name, MyString(value))
  def build(name: String, value: Int): IntVal = IntVal(name, value)
  def build(name: String, value: Double): DoubleVal = DoubleVal(name, value)
}


object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    var fields = Seq.empty[MyVal]
    var row = Map("length" -> 1, "name" -> "test", "cost" -> 2.0)
    var columns = Seq[String]("length", "name", "cost")
    val fields: Seq[MyVal] = row foldLeft (Seq.empty[MyVal]) {
      (previousFields: Seq[MyVal], currentField: Any) => {
        columns map {
          column => MyVal.build(column, Field.build(row(column)))
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The build methods don't resolve correctly because of the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Field` trait defines all possibl types we can have for a field:

```
import scala.language.existentials
import scala.language.implicitConversions

sealed trait Field extends Any {
  def value: Any
}

case class MyString(val value: String) extends AnyVal with Field
case class MyInt(val value: Int) extends AnyVal with Field
case class MyDouble(val value: Double) extends AnyVal with Field
```

Notice the implicit `def`s below. They allow values of known types to be converted to a `Field` without using `build` explicitly. We'll take advantage of it below.

```
object Field {
  implicit def build(value: String): MyString = MyString(value)
  implicit def build(value: Int): MyInt = MyInt(value)
  implicit def build(value: Double): MyDouble = MyDouble(value)
}
```

For `MyVal` we don't need specific subclasses - this would just copy the hiearchy of `Field`. It's enough to say that each value is associated with a `Field` - this captures the same information.

```
sealed case class MyVal(name: String, value: Field)
```

We can still define implicits for being able to build `MyVal`s more easily, although we won't need that.

```
object MyVal {
  // notice that we use the above Field.build.. implicits here:
  implicit def build(name: String, value: String): MyVal = MyVal(name, value)
  implicit def build(name: String, value: Int): MyVal = MyVal(name, value)
  implicit def build(name: String, value: Double): MyVal = MyVal(name, value)
}
```

I wasn't really sure what you're trying to express in your `main` function. Below is somewhat simpler example. The main trick here is that you don't want to have `Map[String,Any]`. This will never work. Once you lose the information what types are in the map, you can't build `Field`s and `MyVal`s out of it without handling somehow invalid values. You want to explicitly keep the information that the values are just the allowed ones, and this is what `Field` is for. By declaring `Map[String,Field]` and letting the `implicit`s do the boring work for you, you get type-safe code below:

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val row = Map[String,Field]("length" -> 1, "name" -> "test", "cost" -> 2.0)
    val vals: Seq[MyVal] = (for((k, v) <- row.iterator) yield MyVal(k, v)).toSeq
  }
}
```

In particular, you want to avoid dealing with type erasure. Typed code is your advantage, type erasure should be left to the run-time as much as possible.